# Why is x / Convert.ToInt32(0) == 0 not throwing an exception in runtime?

Tags: c#

I was going through some trace output questions. And I wonder why is this particular line not throwing an exception?

```
if(x != 10 && x / Convert.ToInt32(0) == 0)
```

- Step 1: `Convert.ToInt32(0) == 0` this will return `true` as 0==0 is
  true
- Step 2: `x/True`?  This should ideally throw Sytem.DivideByZeroException
- Step 3: But if I overall check for "`x != 10 && x / Convert.ToInt32(0) == 0`" it is coming out as "`false`"

Below is code snippet : Output : 2

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x, y = 1;
            x = 10;
            if(x != 10 && x / Convert.ToInt32(0) == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            else
            Console.WriteLine(++y);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Trace : Output

[image]

Comment: Hint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence (`/` has higher precedence than `==`) so it never evaluates `Convert.ToInt32(0) == 0`.

Comment: Note that `x / true` would be a compile-time error, not an exception. You can't divide by Boolean expressions in C#.

Comment: Your code says `if((x != 10) && (((x/Convert.ToInt32(0))  == 0))`. That compiles because your `.ToInt32` call returns an integer, and so `x` divided by the result is an int. But, that code is never evaluated, the C# `&&` operator is _short-circuiting_, so once `x != 10` is evaluated (to false), the entire expression is determined to be false. Get rid of one of the `&`, using only the non-short-circuiting `&` operator and you'll see a divide by zero exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For step 1

You are correct, this part will return `true`.

### For steps 2 and 3

Here's what you're missing:

1. First of all, in C# implicit type casting is limited. The code **would not have compiled at all** if it contained `x / true`. Division operation is not defined for the `bool` type, and the `true` value of Boolean type is not explicitly casted to any other type. Thus it would be a compile error. You may refer to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) if you need help with type casting.
2. Even if we would accept that such division is possible, the `DivideByZeroException` is **not** expected here: you're dividing not by zero, but by `true` value.
3. Another important thing you're missing here is operators precedence. You should learn [operators precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) in C#. You should understand in which order and associations operators are evaluated. If you're not familiar with concepts of operators precedence and associativity, you absolutely should read the whole page that I linked.
4. Lastly, you should understand what are "short-circuiting" Boolean operators. You may refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) to learn about this. In short, this means that when the Boolean expression has calculated one or more operands and now there's enough information to deterministically evaluate the result, other operands are not evaluated at all. This is the case with logical `&&` operator. The operator `&`, for example, is not "short-circuted" and will **always evaluate all of its operands.**

Now let's take your expression apart, step by step:
The left operand of the `&&` operator is evaluated first, because the operation is left-accosiative (evaluates the left operand first). `x != 10` will always evaluate to `false` in your case (since `10` is assigned to `x`).

For the Boolean `and` both operands must be `true` to evaluate the expression to `true`, all the other cases are evaluated to `false` (see the truth table of the Boolean `and`). This makes it obvious that the whole expression will be `false`, no matter to what value the right operand is evaluated to.

Since the `&&` operator is "short-circuted", its evaluation is stopped here. **Thus the right operand, where you expect the `DivideByZeroException`, is not evaluated at all!** This is why you never get the exception you're expecting.

Now let's see what would happen if you either swapped left and right operands or used the not "short-circuted" `&` operator. For this example, I'll just swap the operands: `if(x / Convert.ToInt32(0) == 0 && x != 10)`

First of all, let's substitute your value: `if(10 / Convert.ToInt32(0) == 0 && 10 != 10)`. Once again, the left operand is evaluated first.

The member access operator `.` has the highest precedence in the language. The method call (in your case `Convert.ToInt32`) will be evaluated first. The expression will then look like this: `if(10 / 0 == 0 && 10 != 10)`

The division operator `/` is a *multiplicative operator* and has higher precedence than *equality operators*, such as `==`. In fact, it has the second highest precedence in the whole expression, thus it is now evaluated. At this point you **will get the `DivideByZeroException`**! Try it out yourself.

The exception will also happen if you swap `&&` for `&` in your original code.

### Some general notes and advice

- Make sure you understand the topics I referenced: operators precedence and associativity, Boolean operations and logic, what are "short-circuted" operators.
- Make sure you understand the difference between `&&` and `&` logical operators. They're not the same thing! Typically `&` operator is used very rare in Boolean logic, because "short-circuted" operators are more optimized and have the desired behavior.
- Make sure you understand Boolean logic and truth tables to understand when and why the "short-circuiting" is applied.